# Curses.init_color() won't take effect

Tags: python, python-curses

I'm using Python curses and trying to initialize a new color using curses.init_color(). Even after initializing a new RGB value and assigning it to a pair, the changes won't take effect.

My terminal supports color change since curses.can_change_color() returns True. I've also checked the color index I changed using curses.color_content() - it returned the RGB values I specified in init_color(). I've also called curses.start_color() once at the beginning.

Am I missing something? What do I have to do to make the changes in init_color() take place? Code below:

```
    curses.start_color()
    curses.init_color(17, 200,200,200)

    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_MAGENTA, curses.COLOR_BLACK)    
    curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(3, curses.COLOR_CYAN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(4, 17, curses.COLOR_BLACK)

    print curses.can_change_color() #returns True
    print curses.color_content(17) #(200,200,200), 
    stdscr.addstr("test",curses.color_pair(4)) #yet this text is blue
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I was having the same issue. Hasn't been answered for a year

Answer (score 3):

Your color is just too dark. Try another, more bright color e.g. (800,800,0) to see yellow.

As the [documentation states](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/curses.html#curses.init_color), each RGB component can vary between 0 and 1000, so if we map the (200, 200, 200) color to the standard 8-bit scheme, we get something like that http://colorpeek.com/#rgb(51,51,51).

You can run this demo and see that the `init_color`, `init_pair` and any other functions work as expected. Firstly it prints 8 colors while varying each component only between values 0 and 200. Then it prints more complete palette when components are varying in range (0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import curses


def demo(screen):
    # save the colors and restore it later
    save_colors = [curses.color_content(i) for i in range(curses.COLORS)]
    curses.curs_set(0)
    curses.start_color()

    # use 250 to not interfere with tests later
    curses.init_color(250, 1000, 0, 0)
    curses.init_pair(250, 250, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_color(251, 0, 1000, 0)
    curses.init_pair(251, 251, curses.COLOR_BLACK)

    screen.addstr(0, 20, 'Test colors for r,g,b = {0, 200}\n',
                  curses.color_pair(250) | curses.A_BOLD | curses.A_UNDERLINE)
    i = 0
    for r in (0, 200):
        for g in (0, 200):
            for b in (0, 200):
                i += 1
                curses.init_color(i, r, g, b)
                curses.init_pair(i, i, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
                screen.addstr('{},{},{}  '.format(r, g, b), curses.color_pair(i))

    screen.addstr(3, 20, 'Test colors for r,g,b = {0..1000}\n',
                  curses.color_pair(251) | curses.A_BOLD | curses.A_UNDERLINE)
    for r in range(0, 1001, 200):
        for g in range(0, 1001, 200):
            for b in range(0, 1001, 200):
                i += 1
                curses.init_color(i, r, g, b)
                curses.init_pair(i, i, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
                # screen.addstr('{},{},{} '.format(r, g, b), curses.color_pair(i))
                screen.addstr('test ', curses.color_pair(i))

    screen.getch()
    # restore colors
    for i in range(curses.COLORS):
        curses.init_color(i, *save_colors[i])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(demo)
```

Also, when you change colors with `init_color`, make sure that you restore them before exiting your program, as the terminal colors in the current session will not restore even when you exit your curses program ([color not ended in curses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36051061)).

[image]