# NCURSES color_contents function not returning correct colour intensities

Tags: c, terminal, ncurses

### Update

After some further experimentation it would seem that the ncurses `color_content` function is not reporting the correct colour component values. I wrote the following program to test this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    initscr();
    start_color();
    noecho();

    char *buffer = calloc(COLS + 1, sizeof(*buffer));
    int  offset = 0;
    bool running = true;

    while (running) {
        // Print current offset at top of output
        snprintf(buffer, COLS, "Offset: %i", offset);
        mvchgat(0, 0, -1, A_NORMAL, 0, 0);
        mvaddnstr(0, 0, buffer, COLS);

        // Print each colour with intensities
        for (int y = 1; y < LINES; ++y) {
            short colour = y + offset;
            short r, g, b;

            color_content(colour, &r, &g, &b);

            // Clear line
            memset(buffer, ' ', COLS);
            mvaddnstr(y, 0, buffer, COLS);

            // Render a string with the current colour's intensities
            snprintf(buffer, COLS, "%d\tR: %d\tG: %d\tB: %d", colour, r, g, b);
            mvaddnstr(y, 0, buffer, COLS);

            // Set background of line to the current colour
            init_pair(y, COLOR_WHITE, colour);
            mvchgat(y, 0, -1, A_NORMAL, y, 0);
        }

        // Scroll down and up with the 'j' and 'k' keys and quit with the 'q' key
        int input = getch();

        if (input == 'j' && offset < COLORS - 1)
            ++offset;
        else if (input == 'k' && offset > 0)
            --offset;
        else if (input == 'q')
            running = false;
    }

    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get from the above program clearly demonstrates that the correct intensity values are not being obtained:

[image: Program output demonstrating incorrect intensity values being output by ncurses color_content function]

Why does this happen? Is it possible that ncurses cannot retrieve the colour contents at the start of the program, but only colours that are set with `init_color`?

### Original Question - How to restore terminal colours when closing ncurses

I am developing an ncurses program that makes use of `init_color` to set custom colours. In order to restore terminal colours when the program ends, I have used `color_content` to store the colours at the start of the program. However, using the values retrieved from `color_content` as arguments for `init_color` does not seems to be setting somewhat incorrect colours.

To test this, I have written a small test program that simply uses `color_content` to grab a colour and then immediately uses `init_color` to set the colour:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    initscr();
    start_color();

    short r, g, b;

    for (int i = 0; i < COLORS; ++i) {
        color_content(i, &r, &g, &b);
        init_color(i, r, g, b);
    }

    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

And this program does not restore the colours correctly.

Before:

[image: Terminal colours before program execution]

After:

[image: Terminal colours after program execution]

Is there a way to do this correctly using ncurses?

Comment: Not sure, but a temporary fix is to run `reset` (or maybe `clear`) in the terminal.

Comment: Is this question relevant? [Clean up ncurses mess in terminal after a crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753909/clean-up-ncurses-mess-in-terminal-after-a-crash).

Comment: What is `COLORS` in your code example?

Comment: @SeanBright `COLORS` evaluates to `256` when I print it in gdb.

Comment: @JL2210 both `reset` and `clear` clear the text from the terminal but don't seem to affect the colours

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem here with your code (I had to explicitly define `COLORS` though).

Comment: @SeanBright `start_color` should set `COLORS` https://linux.die.net/man/3/start_color

Comment: Ah, I wasn't linking properly. Works now. Still can't reproduce.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [color not ended in curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051061/color-not-ended-in-curses)

Comment: @ThomasDickey Judging by that answer, it would seem as though it is not possible to fully restore terminal colour with ncurses

Comment: agreed - ncurses doesn't know what the original colors were, and there's no portable way to do this.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Fair enough. Perhaps I should offer it as a custom option to the end user, with a warning that it might mess up their terminal.